# How do I replace each value in run with the integer preceding the run

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Using Mathematica, I have a list:

```
l={0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0}
```

I want to apply a function to the above list to obtain the following:

```
{0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2}
```

Essentially I want to replace the runs of 0 values with runs of the same length, but using the value of the positive integer just preceding each run of 0s.

I thought I could do this easily with FoldList, but I can't see my way through to a solution.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is your test list:

```
tst = {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}
```

The following solution will be reasonably efficient:

```
In[31]:= Module[{n = 0}, Replace[tst, {0 :> n, x_ :> (n = x)}, {1}]]

Out[31]= {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}
```

The way it works is the following: we use the fact that only the first matching rule is applied. The variable `n` stores the last non-zero value encountered by the pattern-matcher during its run through the list. Initially it is set to zero. The first rule replaces `0` with the current value of `n`. If it matches, replacement is made and the pattern-matcher goes on. If it does not match, then we have a non-zero value and the second rule applies, updating the value of `n`. Since the `Set` assignment returns back the value, the non-zero element is simply placed back. The solution should have a linear complexity in the length of the list, and is IMO a good example of the occasional utility of side effects mixed with  rules.

**EDIT**

Here is a functional version:

```
In[56]:= Module[{n = 0}, Map[If[# != 0, n = #, n] &, tst]]

Out[56]= {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}
```

One can check that the rule - based version is about 4 times faster for really large lists. However,
the advantage of this form is that it can easily be `Compile`-d, providing  extreme performance:

```
nzrunsC = 
 Compile[{{l, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Module[{n = 0}, Map[If[# != 0, n = #, n] &, l]], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"]

In[68]:= tstLarge = RandomInteger[{0,2},{10000000}];

In[69]:= nzrunsC[tstLarge];//Timing
Out[69]= {0.047,Null}

In[70]:= Module[{n = 0},Map[If[#!=0,n = #,n]&,tstLarge]];//Timing
Out[70]= {18.203,Null}
```

The difference is several hundred times here, and about a hundred times faster than the rule-based solution. OTOH, rule-based solution will work also with symbolic lists, not necessarily integer lists.

Comment: Would you explain your solution?  I see that it works, but I'm not certain I understand `{0 :> n, x_ :> (n = x)}, {1}]`

Comment: @Leonid This would also overwrite zero runs of length 1. I am not sure the OP considers them as such.

Comment: @David - please see the update, I added an explanation. You could use `ReplaceAll` as well, but then you'd have to use `{0 :> n, x_Integer :> (n = x)}` (otherwise `x_` would match the entire list, since `ReplaceAll` works from expressions to their parts), which would slightly degrade the performance.

Comment: @Sasha Of course, we can not tell without the extra input from the OP, but I don't see why zero runs of length 1 should have any special treatment.

Comment: @Sasha I don't see anything in the question that would suggest runs of length 1 being exempted from replacement.

Comment: @Sjoerd,@Leonid I raised this issues, because [run](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run) is a sequence of something repeated, hence should be length > 1.

Comment: @Leonid +1 for the side effect

Comment: @Sjoerd Of course this solution is just a thin rule-based layer on top of a procedural loop - I was just using `Replace` as a short-cut for `For`, plus don't have to preallocate the result, but the solution is still more procedural than rule-based by nature. But it is shorter and looks neater :)

Comment: @Sasha You may well be right about the OP's intentions. We will have to wait for more information from him.

Comment: @Sjoerd You were reading my thoughts (or vice versa) :) I just finished the `Map`-based version and was about to post it when I saw your comment. See the update.

Comment: @Leonid For my purposes I do want a "run" of one 0 replaced.  Great solution, lesson, and insight. Thx.

Comment: @Leonid Very nice explanation of a subtle replacement.

Answer (score 7):

ReplaceRepeated seems to work fine for this:

```
l //. {f__, x_ /; x != 0, 0, e___} :> {f, x, x, e}

(*   {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}  *)
```

Comment: David, I get the original list back. I'll freely admit, I have no idea why it should work, but is there a mistake in your pattern?

Comment: @recollyer  Hmm.  Works for me. I checked the code to see if if was perhaps pasted incorrectly. But no. It is exactly what I ran. And the output is exactly what I got!

Comment: @Leonid  You're absolutely correct about performance. BTW, for a "random" list of ten thousand 0,1,2's, my routine took 1.25s.  Yours took .0067s.

Comment: @David This is a common situation with this sort of patterns. I actually discussed it here: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node355.html

Comment: `//.` isn't `ReplaceAll`, it's `ReplaceRepeated`.

Comment: @Leonid Thanks. It's been a while since I looked at your lovely book. It's probably time to give it a careful re-reading.

Comment: @David Thanks! The book certainly needs an update (or, more likely, rewrite), since there are just too many important things it does not cover. I hope to address this issue eventually.

Comment: David, sorry. For some reason, the pattern didn't copy correctly.

Comment: @rcollyer That happens to me every once in a while too.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin You should certainly publish it through a publisher this time. I know I'd buy it and you deserve the royalties :)

Comment: @yoda That's what I intend to do. But the main problem is an optimization one: I want to pack it with much more stuff, without sacrificing the clarity, and make it suitable for several levels, "from novice to professional". Goes *very* slowly, I hope to speed it up soon. One of the biggest challenges is that most things are inter-related and hard to explain in a sequential manner.

Comment: @Leonid Some contributions, such as your comments on SO might stand alone as Sidebars. You wouldn't have to work them into the text.

Answer (score 7):

Your original idea of using [FoldList](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FoldList.html) results in the following elegant solution:

```
In[1]:= tst = {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0};

In[2]:= FoldList[If[#2 != 0, #2, #1] &, 0, tst] // Rest                 

Out[2]= {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}
```

This solution is functionally purer because it does not require a helper variable to be set as a side effect, as the rule-based or map-based versions do. It's also faster:

```
In[3]:= tstLarge = RandomInteger[{0, 2}, {10000000}];

In[4]:= Module[{n = 0}, Replace[tstLarge, {0 :> n, x_ :> (n = x)}, {1}]]; // Timing

Out[4]= {5.704, Null}

In[5]:= Module[{n = 0}, Map[If[# != 0, n = #, n] &, tstLarge]]; // Timing

Out[5]= {16.5619, Null}

In[6]:= FoldList[If[#2 != 0, #2, #1] &, 0, tstLarge] // Rest; // Timing

Out[6]= {1.25148, Null}
```